# Expected argument of type "string", "DateTime" given Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, doctrine

I get this error when I'm trying to post a DateType to my database via a form.

My formType.php

```
   $builder
        ->add('date', DateType::class, array(
            'widget' => 'single_text',
        ))
```

My Entity

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
 private $date;
```

I really don't know where the type "string" comes from because I don't specify iy anywhere.

Comment: Most likely your date comes as a string representation from your form and you haven't transformed it into a "DateType" object yet.

Comment: Shouldnt the input field with type "date" do that for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your setter method looks like the following

```
/**
* Set date
*
* @param \DateTime $date
*
* @return EntityName
*/
public function setDate($date)
{
    $this->date = $date;
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: I overlooked the arguments in the set function. The setDate function has string $date. Thanks for the help!